# what is the meaning of "minute debris"?

Tags: expressions

What does "minute debris" mean in the context of an avalanche? I can't find it anywhere.

> The fragments of ice hit the ground around them. The ground beneath
>   his feet trembled and shifted with the onslaught, and MINUTE DEBRIS
>   filled the air with a haze of icy vapor that stung his face. He could
>   barely see, he was running on instinct, no time to think.

Thank you!

Comment: minute sounds like `my nute`

Comment: Perhaps "my newt" would be more user-friendly.

Comment: @JMB depends on how well you trained it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'minute' is an adjective and means 'small.'

'debris' is a noun and means:

> pieces of wood, metal, brick, etc. that are left after something has been destroyed (see http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/debris).

Together, then, it means 'small + pieces of destroyed things'.