# It was a tough question. I thought it through, though. Rules for 'ough'?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, silent-letter

Is there a rule, or rules, for how to pronounce *ough*?

trough  (short o,  gh pronounced f),
thought (short o,  silent gh),
though  (long o,   silent gh),
through (oo,          silent gh),
tough   (short u,  gh pronounced f).

Comment: Hey! You forgot the unvoiced velar fricative, as in _daughter_ (as pronounced in Scotland (by some people)).

Comment: Another hiccough: lough. Unfortunately, there's no rule, not even by the standards of English spelling "rules." You just need to plough through them.

Comment: Also see *[How can native English speakers read an unknown word correctly?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37048/)* and at EL&U, *[Why does the ending -ough have six pronunciations?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31991)* and *[Where do the idiosyncrasies in the spellings of English words come from and why do they survive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47590)* among many others.

Comment: http://www.futilitycloset.com/2009/09/19/o-u-g-h/

Comment: @choster, Great examples! In hiccough, gh sounds like p, the way I pronounce it. In plough, the ou is pronounced ow. You're right, no rule seems to exist. Thanks for the links, also.

Comment: "Hiccough" is a respelling, coming about by folk etymology. The word is pronounced - and commonly spelled - "hiccup". But some time ago (according to etymonline the spelling "hiccough" is first recorded in 1788), some literate souls thought: 'hey, a hiccup is a bit like a cough. Maybe the word is *actually* "hic-cough", but its pronunciation has changed over time.' So they respelled it to reflect their beliefs about the etymology. So the reason why "hiccup" is spelled like that is because "cough" is spelled like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least five ways to pronounce *ough*:

- tough, enough (rhymes with *cuff*)
- through (rhymes with *blue*)
- trough, cough (rhymes with *off*)
- ought, bought (rhymes with *caught*)
- bough (rhymes with *cow*)

As for the rules, the only one I can think of is that the pronunciation found in *thought* only happens with the *ough* is followed by a "t". Other than that, there's really no way to tell by looking at the word.

I remember the first time I met someone with the last name of Gough. I didn't know if it was pronounced as "go", "goff", "guff", or "gow" (that last one rhyming with "now," not "know").

English has many letter combinations like this; consider:

- *earth* vs *hearth*
- *now* vs *low*
- *eight* vs *height*
- *food* vs *blood*
- *pint* vs *lint*

to name but a few. Some words (like *bow* and *wind*) have vowels that can be pronounced two different ways, depending on the meaning of the word, leading to some ambiguous sentences, like this one:

> He took a bow as he gave her a bow.

Comment: Of course, the *t* doesn't *require* rhyming with *thought*, e.g. *drought* (and *drought* is no guide to *draught* either).

Comment: "He took a small bow…. to play his small violin." "Despite being out of breath, the last few turns gave him the wind he needed"  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just one of those things in English that doesn't necessary have a consistent set of rules. You just have to learn them individually. This my perspective as a native English speaker. Someone approaching English as a foreign language may have developed a system of remembering these things, but this is outside my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a rule, really. English is known for it's special spelling at times. There's a dummy word that perfectly describes this:

*Ghoti*, a respelling of the word *fish* and pronounced the same way (/ˈfɪʃ/). It uses the sounds *gh* from *enough*, *o* from *women* and ti from *intention* (not necessarily those words, but those sounds).

It just goes to show that the English pronunciation can be quite unpredictable at times if your point when you're basing it on spelling. So speaking the language correctly is just a matter of studying the pronunciation of tthe words or relying on your language instinct.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that nobody would _really_ pronounce "ghoti" as "fish". The "gh" combination doesn't make the "f" sound at the beginning of a word, and the "ti" combination doesn't make the "sh" sound except in combinations such as "-tion" or "-tian". So, contrary to what the "ghoti" example is intended to illustrate, there _are_ a handful of rules that can be applied.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't ever pronounce ghoti that way. There are several rules and conventions. That word was just invented to illustrate the many irregularities that do exist in the language.

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but I'm not sure that would have been crystal clear to the novice learner reading your answer and seeing that word for the first time, so I wanted to add a comment.

Comment: Perfectly understandable, I should've thought of that.