# Is there any rule how to pronounce words with endings "-ough"?

Tags: pronunciation

I found two pronunciations for the same ending (ugh), one sounds like F, and the other one sounds like omitting of the ending ugh.

That's what I found and you're happily invited to edit this post and to add more examples or change incorrect examples:

**Sounds like f**: tho**ugh**, to**ugh**, co**ugh**.

**Sounds like omitting the ending**: bough, dough, thorough, slough, through

**Sounds like p**: hicco**ugh**

Anyway, I couldn't find a rule which can explain when it should be pronounced as p, f, or be omitted. Is there such rule?

Comment: As a note, in some dialects (BrE, I think) hiccough is pronounced like "cough".

Comment: @Catija - No.  We pronounce the word like it has a 'p' on the end in BrE and I am unaware of any dialects pronouncing it like it has an 'f' on the end

Comment: @AdorableSpectacle - **Though** is pronounced with the same ending as dough

Comment: To complicate matters, _slough_ can be pronounced [with an _f_ sound](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/slough_1), or with [no _f_ sound](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/slough_2), depending on the meaning. And I don’t think there’s any “rule” for this; _ough_ has a few possible pronunciations and they are what they are.

Comment: Nine pronunciations of "ough" are listed in one answer to "[How can native English speakers read an unknown word correctly?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37048#37080)"

Answer (score 1):

As [EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_of_7/7_Ways_to_Say_ough__2924.htm) says

> In some languages, you can look at a word and know immediately how to pronounce it. But in English you need to be a little more careful.

There is no rule for pronunciations of words ending in *ugh* and there are 8 different ways to pronounce the end of these words (see the link above).

> English words are not always that difficult. But in general, when you learn a new word, you should also make sure you know its pronunciation. If you do not have a teacher or someone to say the word for you, you can look in a dictionary. All good dictionaries give the pronunciation for each word, often with special symbols. So it's a good idea to look at your dictionary carefully and learn the pronunciation symbols. After that, you'll always be able to find the pronunciation of any word, easily