# English people names and street names

Tags: names

I know learning grammar and vocab is so painful, but that's not the hardest part to me. What makes me feel most difficult is the English name for people and streets.

They are complicated, no spelling pattern, and some of them are not easy to pronounce.

So, I would want to know how native English speaker learns people and street names and naturally remember them?

Is there any way I can learn them?

Comment: How did you learn the names in your native language? It's the same. It just takes time. There's no secret.

Comment: @Catija - Well, most other languages have much more predictable orthography/pronunciation.  English is particularly bad that way.

Comment: Our street and people names are base on the meaning of the word. Every word in their names is meaningful.

Comment: @stangdon Sure... but that's because it's a mish mash of a half dozen different languages... but the point is the same... Even as an adult, there's no way to know how to spell a name without asking unless you've heard it before. Heck, my name has dozens of different spellings and all of them are correct to someone.

Comment: Not to mention that, in some languages, like Japanese, there are often several different ways to spell names (using kanji) because the sounds overlap between different options.

Comment: @GoldenEggs - English words that you don't already know are notoriously difficult to pronounce correctly.  We borrowed a lot of words and names from different languages, and sometimes we changed the spelling and sometimes we changed the pronunciation, and sometimes we changed both.

Comment: You might be interested in [How can native English speakers read an unknown word correctly?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37048/how-can-native-english-speakers-read-an-unknown-word-correctly) and [How do native speakers 'guess' the pronunciation of the letters in a word they see for the first time?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59128/how-do-native-speakers-guess-the-pronunciation-of-the-letters-in-a-word-they-s)

Comment: @Catjia In my language, once we learned some basic words, then there is no trouble with names. For example: West Lake Road, Maple street (Translated to English)

Comment: @GoldenEggs - We have plenty of names like West Lake Road and Maple Street too.   But a lot of the time the names either don't mean anything, or the meaning isn't relevant.  For example, Lexington Avenue is named after a village called Lexington, which is named after *another* village called Lexington, and the name means something like "farm of the people of a man called Leaxa"...but nobody but historians is going to know that or care.  Likewise, Paris, Texas is named after Paris, France, which is named after the Parisii tribe of the Celts, but how is knowing that going to help you?

Comment: @stangdon Would English native speakers have experienced difficult in learning names? I ask that because I know exactly what you mean about those "foreign" names.

Comment: @GoldenEggs - Yes, sometimes.  For example, visiting New Orleans is very confusing, because the street names there are almost never pronounced like you would think.  [The Muse Calliope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliope) is pronounced "ka-LY-uh-pee" but Calliope Street in New Orleans is pronounced "CAL-ee-ope".  Iberville isn't pronounced in the French way, but like "EYE-ber-ville." And good luck figuring out the difference between Nachitoches, Louisiana and Nacogdoches, Texas without help!  (They're "NAK-uh-tesh" and "nak-uh-DOH-chis", respectively.)

Comment: We learn them by using the pronunciation and spelling given to us by either the person himself or someone who knows them; if either one is wrong, someone will correct us.

Comment: @stangdon and Lima, Peru (Leema) vs Lima, Ohio (lyema, like the bean).

Comment: @Catija - And a friend told me about Bogotá, Colombia (bo-go-TA) vs. Bogota, New Jersey (buh-GOAT-uh).

Answer (score 1):

La Jolla California, is an example; unless you know the 'J' is soft like an 'H', many would pronounce it with the hard J. If you don't speak French, or are not Catholic and know Pius 1X is a pope, you might not pronounce Pius IX as something like Pea Neuf in Montreal.  I doubt there's anyway to get how something is pronounced unless a native tells you.

I was skiing at Mont Tremblant when an American fellow asked me how to find the Grand Pricks. The Grand Prix is a pretty famous auto race, but he did not know that!

Comment: I typed "La Jolla" several times before I realized that this was the place pronounced "La Hoya" (not La Joe-La). And when I moved to Atlanta, my friend's mom told me to exit the highway at "Ponts Duh Lee-on", which is how everyone in Atlanta pronounces it, but it is spelled "Ponce de Leon". Also, Houston is pronounced "House-tin". Being a native speaker did not help; I had to learn the local pronunciations.

Comment: @Davo - Wait, are you saying Houston is pronounced that way in Atlanta, or what?  Houston, TX is normally pronounced HYOO-stən, I thought, but Houston Street in NYC is HOUSE-tin.

Comment: The US has towns name Covington; I've heard it pronounced three different ways in three different states. And then there's a favorite of mine, Wilkes-Barre PA  – it's pronounced as if it's spelled "Wilksberry". Yes, regional variations abound.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, in Atlanta it's pronounced HOWZ-tin. And [Dacula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacula,_Georgia) is pronounced duh-KYOO-luh.

Comment: Don't even get me started with Schuylkill.

Comment: Some other American examples: DeKalb GA (or a county in AL) versus IL. The "L" is only pronounced in the latter. Quincy MA versus IL: The "C" sounds like a "Z" in Massachusetts. In fact Mass has all kinds of weird pronunciations (Worcester, Leominster), many of them owing to UK place names.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive: And Mass has some weird pronunciations (Woburn, Haverhill) even when the same UK place names are pronounced the way they're spelled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot learn names 'naturally', but you can learn them if you put effort into remembering them, such as repeating them over and over in your head. Even native speakers do this, not because they find them hard to say, but because they are naturally forgetful!

Because of this, they will be understanding about any issues you have with names, so don't worry about asking for help. It's one of the best ways to improve on any aspect of a language. I would recommend explaining that you are not a native speaker, and find names particularly difficult. You could even ask people to say their names slowly, and perhaps repeat them a couple of times.

Again: don't be afraid that this will annoy people. In fact, they'll be touched that you're making an effort. Not many people appreciate how much people like it when you take an interest in their names. Names are the primary way that people identify themselves, and anything that shows you're trying to get them right, is worth doing. This also applies to street names: it's important to people because it's where they live.

If you have have any close native English friends, you could always ask them instead when you see them later. If not, you'll probably acquire more friends there anyway, over time.

Eventually, as you practise name pronunciation more and more, it will get easier, just like the grammar and vocabulary did.

Answer (score 0):

We native speakers don't always get these names right, either! (You'll see this below.)

Aside from the very salient answers already given, I'm inclined to suggest that you choose one geographical area. Of course the English language is used natively in a diverse set of nations across the globe, so I'm afraid you'll drive yourself crazy trying to learn so many diverse people's names or place names at once!

For example, you might live or might like to live in London, in British Columbia, in Southeast Texas, in Lagos, or in Western Australia; or you might have contact with people from one of those places. So you could focus on the names from those places, only learning the others as needed.

For example, major US cities' names come from the following origins:

- **English place names**: New York, Boston, Birmingham
- **French place names**: New Orleans
- **Greek**: Philadelphia
- **Spanish**: Los Angeles, San Francisco, El Paso (less prominent: Las Cruces, Boca Raton)
- **Native languages**: Chicago (a wild onion), Seattle (from a chief's name)
- **Egyptian place name**: Memphis
- **Contemporary people's names**: Nashville, Raleigh, Washington, Pittsburgh, Houston, Dallas, Denver
- **Saints' names**: Saint Louis, Saint Paul
- **Geographical features**: Little Rock, Salt Lake City
- **Latin**: Cincinnati
- **Hybrid native/Greek**: Minneapolis

Also note that New York City, formerly Nieuw Amsterdam, has ***many*** Dutch (Netherlands) place names, adapted to English inconsistently. For example the name of the Van Wyck Expressway [is somewhat controversial](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/26/nyregion/van-wyck-expressway-also-snarls-pronunciation.html).

Any other large English-speaking country might have its own mix. And the problem is, each of those source languages is going to have its own phonology. Sometimes we get it wrong--before I recently traveled to Abuja, I was pronouncing the name of Nigeria's capital with the accent on the wrong syllable. And I'm still not sure if one form of Lagos or the other is favored!

So I strongly suggest you focus on the part of the English-speaking world most of interest to you and learn the rest only as needed.

Comment: [Forvo](https://forvo.com/) is extremely helpful for hearing recordings of native speakers, keyed to their geographical location.